# Getting starred expression error in Python - robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am getting "starred expressions can't use here" error message for any program I write. I am getting error in "Settings", "variables" and "keywords and Testcases". Attached image screenshots for reference.
I had installed all the plugins (Intellibot) and interpreters as well. Please advise me on this.

```
Robot Framework version : 3.0.2
Robot Framework selenium library : 3.1.1
Python - 3.6.5
selenium : 3.12.0
```

Starred Expressions Error:

[image: Starred Expressions Error]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghNfJ.png)

Comment: "starred expressions can't use here" doesn't sound like a robot error, and it doesn't appear in your screenshot. Can you please include the actual error message?

Comment: Thanks Bryan for responding to my question. I added the screenshot along with the error message.

Comment: Have you installed a plugin that supports robot? It doesn't look like you have.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, it seems like you have a lib installed in conflict with robotframework, can you try installing your project environment in a separate virtualenv ? That would resolve the problem

Comment: I have installed "robot & IntelliBot" plug ins and created project in a new virtual environment. Still facing the same issue. Attaching the screenshot for reference.

Comment: Thank you all, Issue is resolved for me. Solution: Cleared cache and upgraded the versions of Python and Robot Framework